# How do I retrieve all files in VS Code?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, trailhead, sfdx-plugin, superbadges

I'm working on the [Apex Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_apex) super badge on the Salesforce Trailhead. I'm also trying to get more comfortable with Visual Studio Code with the Salesforce extensions.

I've successfully create a project and connected it to the playground organization. I then tried to get the source code by executing `SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org`, and it did get two files I created (a class and its metadata `xml` file), but not everything.

The super badge project provides an unlocked package that I installed into the org. Part of this package were template files for classes and triggers. The exercise expects us to edit this files, and I have done so to some extent, but these files weren't retrieved.

How do I get all the files onto my local machine for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the command says retrieve **source in Manifest** from org, that's the trick it only retrieves whats configured or specified in manifest, go to the sfdx project folder inside it you will find a manifest folder , inside it a file named package.xml this is where its specified what to retrieve from the org

A sample manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>SampleClass</members>
        <members>SampleTestClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>InvoiceTemplate</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Checkbox</members>
        <members>Logo</members>
        <members>Signature</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

As you can see inside types the name specifies the type of metadata I want to pull and members contain the names of the resources
Do this trailhead module to get a idea:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/package-xml/package-xml-manifest

Recently you will find sfdx projects in Vscode have **org browser**, you can use this to click pull the data if you don't want to go through the hassle of manifest(It works on the default org)

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser/

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I did look at the `package.xml` file, but figured the `*` meant "all Apex Classes" and "all Apex Triggers." I'll be sure to go through that module.

Comment: yup you are absolutely correct '*' is a wild character depicting all .....do go through sfdx modules on trailhead they are a great learning resource

Comment: I went through the module you linked to. It did help explain quite a bit. But you said that `*` within the `members` tag indicates "all" of whatever type it's in. But the default manifest I get when creating a project has `*` for all the types, but running `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml -u ...` doesn't retrieve the files until I explicitly list them (i.e., `<members>MaintenanceRequest</members>`). If `*` indicates "all members," why do I have to manually list them?

Answer (score 1):

For any superbadge, you will have to install a package before starting. Copy the name of the package and use this command in the terminal.

$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -n NameOfThePackage

This will retrieve all the components in the package into a new folder named as the package.

Hope this helps.